# How to compile libfacerec in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I am using OpenCV 2.3 and need to compile libfacerec by bytefish because opencv 2.3 does not support **FaceRecognizer**. However I was able to generate MakeFile using cmake CMakeLists.txt but when I use make command it gives error. Can somebody please help me out I am new at this. My current environment is Ubuntu 12.04. I cant use opencv 2.4 just need to add support in opencv 2.3. 
Thanks

Comment: make command gives *which* error ?

Comment: -- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/salman/Downloads/libfacerec-0.04
[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/opencv_facerec.dir/src/helper.cpp.o
In file included from /home/salman/Downloads/libfacerec-0.04/src/helper.cpp:19:0:
/home/salman/Downloads/libfacerec-0.04/include/helper.hpp:54:18: error: ‘InputArray’ was not declared in this scope
..
..


make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/opencv_facerec.dir/src/helper.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/opencv_facerec.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: I think I might have to add some path in make file or CMakeLists.txt but dont know what